# create source.jar with cmake without maven

Tags: java, cmake

I would like to generate a source file jar (source.jar) via cmake -- without maven support.

By using add_jar(), I can create the binary java bindings for my project using cmake, but not source.jar
From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html) , I could not find a useful lead to solve the issue.

Any idea on how to generate the jar via cmake?

Comment: If you have a JDK installed what is there to stop you from running the same commands that you would from the command line for `jar`?

Comment: Please let us know the reason why you don't want to use Maven for this task. It will be useful to understand the context around the question.

Comment: @g00se I could use the same commands to create jar, but I didn't know the combination of cmake commands to use.

Comment: @aled not using maven is the requirement of the task.

Answer (score 0):

[add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) needs to be used in combination with [add_custom_target()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

add_custom_command() is used to build the file with dependencies and add_custom_target() to build it to target.

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "sources.jar"
        COMMAND jar -cf "sources.jar" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        VERBATIM
        COMMENT "creating sources jar"
)

add_custom_target(SourcesJar
        ALL
        DEPENDS "sources.jar"
        )
```